# Sencha 2 navigation view create new instance of view without replacing old one

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a navigation view with list(A) as its item.
On clicking the list(A) item, showing new view(B).
Now the new view(B) is having one button on clicking again change to view(C).

Problem is 
view(C) is same as view(B).

I am able to create the new view and push it, but not able to populate with new data.
and on coming back to view(B), I am getting the data of view(C).

How to solve this scenario.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * navigationview with list(A) 
 */
Ext.define('activity', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    config: {
        items:[
            {
                grouped:true,
                pinHeaders:   true,
                xtype:'list',
                store:{
                    xclass:'ActivityList'
                },
                itemTpl:'{title}',
                emptyText: 'nothing found'
            }
        ]
    }
});

/**
 * child view(B) to be appeared on clicking any item in list(A).
 */
Ext.define('TaskDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config:   {
        title:  'Task',
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items:  [
            {
                xtype:  'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                height: '40px',
                items:  [
                    { xtype: 'spacer'},
                    {
                        xtype:        'segmentedbutton',
                        height:       '30px',
                        items:        [
                            {
                                text:    'Task Details',
                                pressed: true
                            },
                            {
                                text:      'Child Tasks',
                                badgeText: '0'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    { xtype: 'spacer'}
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:  'container',
                items:  [
                    {
                        xtype:'dataview',
                        store:     {
                            xclass: 'TaskDetails'
                        },
                        itemTpl:   'some thing....'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'list',
                        store:{
                            xclass:'ChildTask'
                        },
                        itemTpl: 'some template...'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

I am changing view in controller and want to show the same view(B)again with new data on clicking the list in view(B).

Comment: It would help us to see your code. Especially how you populate data for the view(C)

Comment: There is no view(C). I want view(B) with new data. And also I dont want to re write new class, and also want to maintain previous data.

Comment: The code of the views is not really helpful. Could you post the controllers' code ?

Comment: my controller is not complicated. I am just pushing the view and passing the data.   this.view.push(Ext.create('TaskDetails', {data:record.data,view: inst.view}));

Comment: And what would this.view and inst.view be ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of navigation view which you cannot circumvent. Use setActiveItem instead to push views... I had the same issue and changed to setActiveItem it gives you more control of your views than navigation view so

Answer (score 0):

After you first load the view(2), the ref returns an array of 1, as it should. Refs only work if 1 component is returned.

After you load the view(2) again  the ref returns an array of 2.

This means none of the listeners fire and the data doesn't load on new instances.

Refs bind to dom elements when controllers first see a view. We can't change that. This means we can't use a ref directly. We know the Ext.ComponentQuery.query is what refs rely on. Using that, we can simulate refs at runtime. I put a runtime dataview ref in the initialize() function of the controller to load the data for a new view. This seems to run every time a view is created, so it works.